# Error while renaming and uploading file using PHP - Undefined index

Tags: php, uploading, renaming

Below is the given code. I want to renamen the file before uploading. On submitting it is showing error: Undefined index.

```
        if($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']==true)
        {
            $SPPic = ($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']);
            $curTime = time();
            $NewPriorPic = "prior";
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$SGeiNo;
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$SSurgDt;
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$curTime;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['tmp_name'] , "upload_pictures/".$_FILES['$NewPriorPic']['name']);
        }
    else
        {
            $SPPic = "NIL";
        }
```

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Check your usage of quotes at the line starting with `move_uploaded_file(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For future reference, if anyone needed.

```
    if($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']==true)
        {
            $SPPic = ($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']);
            $ext = pathinfo($SPPic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $curTime = time();
            $NewPriorPic = "prior";
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$SGeiNo;
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$SSurgDt;
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.$curTime;
            $NewPriorPic = $NewPriorPic.".".$ext;
            $location = "upload_pictures/";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['tmp_name'], $location.$NewPriorPic);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed this line a little bit up:

(You forgot the start quote)

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['tmp_name'] , upload_pictures/".$_FILES['$NewPriorPic']['name']);
```

So change it to this:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['tmp_name'] , "upload_pictures/" . $_FILES[$NewPriorPic]['name']);
```

Comment: quotes are there, may be during copy paste i messed it up. let me edit it in question.

Comment: @Sandhu Which error do you get exactly? and on which line?

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code and your logic seems to be little confusing of what you are trying to achieve, but you can try this:

```
 <?php    
  if($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']) {
            $SPPic = ($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['name']);
            $curTime = time();
            $NewPriorPic = "prior";
            //Add aditional details to the file name
            $NewPriorPic .= $SGeiNo;
            $NewPriorPic .= $SSurgDt;
            $NewPriorPic .= $curTime;
            //Try to move uploaded file   
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FPScreenShot']['tmp_name'] , "upload_pictures/".$_FILES[$NewPriorPic]['name'])) {
               echo "File successfully uploaded.";  
            }
            else {
               echo "Error while uploading the file.";
            }
        }
    else {
            $SPPic = "NIL";
        }
```